# Prevent activity from loading until task has completed

Tags: android

I have 3 activities:

1. MainActivity
2. Activity A
3. Activity B

The user can start a process in Activity B.  I show a notification helper % completed, and I go back to MainActivity.

But I don't want to user to be able to do anything with the app until the process had completed, so basically - there is a button on MainActivity that I want to be disabled until the process has completed.

Anyway to check if the notificationbar is still there when they click a button, or anyway to check if the async task is still running?

Thanks

Comment: You will get to notified in `onPostExec` of the `Async task` whenever the process is completed...

Comment: Thanks but can you disable a button in a different activity?

Comment: The button is on Main Activity, but the Async Task is on Activity B

Comment: and u wanna disable button in MainActivity?? I guess MainActivtiy wont be visible at the time of Activtiy B running...

Answer (score 0):

```
private class DownloadStuff extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
     protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
       // DO STUFF in Background
         return null;
     }

     protected Void onPostExecute() {
         // Disable Button
     }
}
```

More info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: The button I wish to disable is in the MainActivity, but the Async task is in activity B

Answer (score 0):

ok use this in asynctask

**on preExecute()**

```
button1.setEnabled(false);
```

**on postExecute()**

```
button1.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: ok but does it matter that the Button is in a different activity?

Comment: no u must be calling ur asyntask task in each activity  guess... where u call the activity set it there. it will help

Answer (score 0):

By  Use of [Async Task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) u can solve that

Answer (score 0):

Think to use something like :

**MainActivity.java**

```
MainActivity implements LoadingTaskFinishedListener

@Override
    public void onTaskFinished() {
        myButton.setEnabled(true);  
    }
```

..

```
public class Task extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {


    Actualite[] pages;
    int i=0;
    public interface LoadingTaskFinishedListener {
        void onTaskFinished();
    }
```